# Extracting multiple strings from a column with comma separated values

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame like this:

```
structure(list(mut = c("Q184H/CAA-CAT", "I219V/ATC-GTC", "A314T/GCG-ACG, P373Q/CCG-CAG, A653E/GCG-GAA","0")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want to do is to get everything after the "/" in a new column, for each comma separated value in each row, regardless of how many entries are in each row.

What I want to end up with:

```
    mut                    nt
1   Q184H                  CAA-CAT
2   I219V                  ATC-GTC
3   A314T, P373Q, A653E    GCG-ACG, CCG-CAG, CGC-GAA
4   0                      0
```

I have tried to use a regular expression for this, but can't seem to match every entry separated by comma.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(nt = gsub(".+/(.*?)", "\\1", mut))
```

How do I make this match every entry? Do I have to split them apart then do matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tweak your regex a bit; notice how I've changed your `.`s to `[^,]`s. In a regex, if you put characters surrounded by brackets and preceded by a `^`, it means match anything *but* these characters. So `[^,]+` means match as many consecutive characters as you can that are not commas.

```r
df = structure(list(mut = c("Q184H/CAA-CAT", "I219V/ATC-GTC",
                            "A314T/GCG-ACG, P373Q/CCG-CAG, A653E/GCG-GAA","0")),
               row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>%
    mutate(nt = gsub("[^,]+?/([^,]+?)", "\\1", mut),
           mut = gsub("([^/]+)/[^,]+", "\\1", mut))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   mut                 nt                     
#>   <chr>               <chr>                  
#> 1 Q184H               CAA-CAT                
#> 2 I219V               ATC-GTC                
#> 3 A314T, P373Q, A653E GCG-ACG,CCG-CAG,GCG-GAA
#> 4 0                   0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! So the square brackets specify that the comma "can" be there, but doesn't have to?

Comment: @Haakonkas I added a bit of additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

*Do not* accept this as an answer (@duckmayr did the regex debugging). Posting this soley to show folks that by using `stringi` we can get self-documenting regular expressions so our future self(s) do not end up hating our past self(s):

```
library(stringi) # it's what stringr uses
library(tidyverse)

xdf <- structure(list(mut = c("Q184H/CAA-CAT", "I219V/ATC-GTC", "A314T/GCG-ACG, P373Q/CCG-CAG, A653E/GCG-GAA","0")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mutate(
  xdf, 
  nt = stri_replace_all_regex(
    str = mut,
    pattern = "
[^,]+?  # match anything but a comma and if there is one, match at most once
/       # followed by a forward slash
(       # start of match group
 [^,]+? # same as above
)       # end of match group
",
    replacement = "$1", # take the match group value as the value
    opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(comments=TRUE)
  ),
  mut = stri_replace_all_regex(
    str = mut,
    pattern = "
(      # start of match group
 [^/]+ # match anything but a forward slash
)      # end of match group
/      # followed by a forward slash
[^,]+  # match anything but a comma
",
    replacement = "$1", # take the match group value as the value
    opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(comments=TRUE)
  )
)
```

Comment: That's actually really cool -- I had no idea that functionality existed

Comment: Aye. It's a life-saver for those truly gnarly regexes that work _perfectly_ until they don't and you have to remember what you were thinking 4 years ago :-) Yours was extremely straightforward but it provided a good opportunity to provide a compact example (there are so few examples of regexes with documentation; I'm as guilty as anyone of not doing that even when I answer q's with `stringi`).